# C++ Win API Specify Custom toolbar Bitmap?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, bitmap, toolbars

Picture and c++ files can be found here: http://phantomworksstudios.com/cpp/ss/

Ok so I have been having a lot of problems with my toolbars. such as them not displaying correctly, can't set the button size via height and width no matter what I do, the bitmaps are off set by 1 pixel to the right which are the back,forward,stop, etc icons. and the other icons such as the clip board and new file which is the last tool bar under the rest are cut off bad. I think its still trying to strip the tool bar list as 16x16 but the bitmap I have icons as 14x14.

The icons are within a bmp file which is 32 bit depth
one is 16x16 while the last one is 14x14

I have no idea what is going on and no matter what I can't seem to get it working like it should:

[image]

Comment: All icons for the Win32 toolbar need to be the same size. And you need to set the size (width x height) of the toolbar buttons to match the size of the icons, else you'll get the "shifting" effects that you describe. If you're familiar with CSS, you can think of the toolbar image resource as similar to a CSS sprite.

Comment: ok so how to I go about changing the button size? I tried using 
TB_SETBUTTONWIDTH and TB_SETBUTTONSIZE with no luck. In my command window it shows those two command returning 1 not 0 so any ideas on whats going on here?   Thanks I really appreciate it

Comment: Ok so I'm still going through all of my code and I still can't figure out why it doesn't have any effect of changing the button size. I'm still looking around on google and yahoo(Even the Yahoo Answers) and I still have no luck :( other then specifying the TB_SETBUTTONSIZE which returns 1 with no effect.

Comment: ok I was wrong, it will change the button size only if its bigger. It won't change the size smaller then 16 why? IF the number is bigger then 16 it will change it but anything under it doesn't work...